# Elasticsearch faceting query

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if I can write a faceting query for something like this

My document structure

```
UserID, AnswerID[] (int array)
1 , [9,10,11,56,78,99]
2 , [10,11,56,78,99]
3 , [8,10,12,56, 79,99]
4 , [9,10,11,56,78,99]
```

If I just want the count of users who answered 9,56 I can write a query. But I have two lists

```
List A - 9,10,11
ListB - 56,78,99
```

I want the permutation of the two lists.

Count of users who answered [9,56], [9,78], [9,99], [10,56], [10,78], [10,99], [11,56]...

How do I write a query to achieve something like this.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can work when not using lists:

```
# Print ES Version
curl 'http://localhost:9200/'

# Delete the index `testindex`
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/testindex'

# Create the index `testindex`
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testindex' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
        }
    }
}'

# Wait for yellow
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow'

# Index docs
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testindex/type/1 -d '{ "listA":"value1", "listB":"value2" }'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testindex/type/2 -d '{ "listA":"value1", "listB":"value3" }'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testindex/type/3 -d '{ "listA":"value1", "listB":"value2" }'

# Refresh docs
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_refresh'

# TermFacet
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/type/_search?pretty' -d '
{
   "query": { "match_all" : {} },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script_field" : "_source.listA + \" - \" + _source.listB"
            }
        }
    }   
}'
```

Gives:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testindex",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : { "listA":"value1", "listB":"value2" }
    }, {
      "_index" : "testindex",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : { "listA":"value1", "listB":"value3" }
    }, {
      "_index" : "testindex",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : { "listA":"value1", "listB":"value2" }
    } ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "tag" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 0,
      "total" : 0,
      "other" : -3,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "value1 - value2",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "value1 - value3",
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea when using list... I would love to know if it can be done...